# Python Pandas: pivot only certain columns in the DataFrame while keeping others

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to re-arrange a DataFrame that I automatically read in from a json using Pandas. I've searched but have had no success.

I have the following json (saved as a string for copy/paste convenience) with a bunch of json objects/dictionarys under the tag 'value'

```
json_str = '''{"preferred_timestamp": "internal_timestamp",
    "internal_timestamp": 3606765503.684,
    "stream_name": "ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument",
    "values": [{
        "value_id": "temperature",
        "value": 9.8319
    }, {
        "value_id": "conductivity",
        "value": 3.58847
    }, {
        "value_id": "pressure",
        "value": 22.963
    }]
}'''
```

I use the function 'json_normalize' in order to load the json into a flattened Pandas dataframe.

```
>>> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> df = json_normalize(json.loads(json_str), 'values', ['preferred_timestamp', 'stream_name', 'internal_timestamp'])
>>> df
      value      value_id preferred_timestamp  internal_timestamp  \
0   9.83190   temperature  internal_timestamp        3.606766e+09   
1   3.58847  conductivity  internal_timestamp        3.606766e+09   
2  22.96300      pressure  internal_timestamp        3.606766e+09   
3  32.89470      salinity  internal_timestamp        3.606766e+09   

               stream_name  
0  ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument  
1  ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument  
2  ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument  
3  ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument
```

Here is where I am stuck. I want to take the value and value_id columns and pivot these into new columns based off of value_id.

I want the dataframe to look like the following:

```
stream_name              preferred_timestamp  internal_timestamp  conductivity  pressure  salinity  temperature    
ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument  internal_timestamp   3.606766e+09        3.58847       22.96300  32.89470  9.83190
```

I've tried both the pivot and pivot_table Pandas functions and even tried to manually pivot the tables by using 'set_index' and 'stack' but it's not quite how I want it.

```
>>> df.pivot_table(values='value', index=['stream_name', 'preferred_timestamp', 'internal_timestamp', 'value_id'])
stream_name              preferred_timestamp  internal_timestamp  value_id    
ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument  internal_timestamp   3.606766e+09        conductivity     3.58847
                                                                  pressure        22.96300
                                                                  salinity        32.89470
                                                                  temperature      9.83190
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

This is close, but it didn't seem to pivot the values in 'value_id' into separate columns.

and

```
>>> df.pivot('stream_name', 'value_id', 'value')
value_id                 conductivity  pressure  salinity  temperature
stream_name                                                           
ctdpf_j_cspp_instrument       3.58847    22.963   32.8947       9.8319
```

Close again, but it lacks the other columns that I want to be associated with this line.

I'm stuck here. Is there an elegant way of doing this or should I split the DataFrames and re-merge them to how I want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your first attempt was nearly correct, just use `columns='value_id'` instead of including it in the index.

```
# Perform the pivot.
df = df.pivot_table(
    values='value',
    index=['stream_name', 'preferred_timestamp', 'internal_timestamp'],
    columns='value_id'
    )

# Formatting.
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns.name = None
```

This isn't an issue in your example data, but keep in mind that `pivot_table` will aggregate values if multiple values are pivoted to the same position (taking the mean by default).

Comment: Thank you! It's always something so small that is the issue.... What would be the appropriate procedure for pivoting multiple values?

Comment: It's likely situation specific, but there are a few options.  If aggregation makes sense, you can specify how to aggregate, including using custom functions you define elsewhere in your code, e.g. `agg_func='max'` or `agg_func=custom_function`.  If there are specific values you want to keep, you can do some preprocessing to remove values you don't want to include. An option to keep duplicates separate is to add a dummy column to make your pivot unique, and then drop it after pivoting.

Comment: This method seems to fails if one of the original columns contains `lists` as values - this then throughs up `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error when trying to include it in `index`.  Any suggestions?  Thanks