# How to pivot dataframe without changing index and returning all columns from previous operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a table :

[image]

When I try to pivot in python:

```
df.pivot(columns = 'Type', values = 'Value')
```

it returns only columns from Type column with values but columns Col1-Col5 do not appear in my dataframe

In Power Query it's achieved very simple, I just choose column I want to pivot and values for this column:
[image]

And after this operation I get following result:

[image]

How do I achieve the same result using pd.pivot ?

Thanks!

Comment: share actual data, instead of pics

Comment: It's actually the same , just 15 more columns before Type and Month columns, they are primarily some IDs, Names etc

Answer (score 0):

In no way using `pd.pivot`. There is the `pd.pivot_table` function made for this case:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'], 
columns=['Type'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to do this, same steps as outlined [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021151/6121794)

```
res = df.pivot_table(values='Value', index=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'], columns='Type')
```

This creates a multi-index dataframe, which you can then flatten:

```
res.reset_index(inplace=True)
res.columns.name = None
```

Comment: Getting 'DataError: No numeric types to aggregate' although 'Values' column has float numbers in it :(

Comment: can you post a subset of the dataset? ideally something easy to reproduce directly, these guidelines are a good reference point: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example