# Python Pandas: how to only pivot certain columns while keeping others?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019788/python-pandas-pivot-only-certain-columns-in-the-dataframe-while-keeping-others) with a very similar title, but the answer there doesn't seem to apply to my problem.

I have the following dataframe:

```
                           date  hour  rating category  value
date_time                                                    
2020-02-01 00:00:00  2020-02-01     1    30.0       C1   41.5
2020-02-01 01:00:00  2020-02-01     2    32.4       C1   54.1
2020-02-01 02:00:00  2020-02-01     3    31.1       C1   40.9
2020-02-01 00:00:00  2020-02-01     1     NaN       C2   51.5
2020-02-01 01:00:00  2020-02-01     2     NaN       C2   50.6
2020-02-01 02:00:00  2020-02-01     3     NaN       C2   42.3
2020-02-02 00:00:00  2020-02-02     1    36.8       C1   47.8
2020-02-02 01:00:00  2020-02-02     2    30.1       C1   50.1
2020-02-02 02:00:00  2020-02-02     3    30.5       C1   44.0
2020-02-02 00:00:00  2020-02-02     1     NaN       C2   46.8
2020-02-02 01:00:00  2020-02-02     2     NaN       C2   44.2
2020-02-02 02:00:00  2020-02-02     3     NaN       C2   45.2
```

Which I would like to transform to this:

```
                           date  hour  rating  C1    C2   
date_time                                                    
2020-02-01 00:00:00  2020-02-01     1    30.0  41.5  51.5
2020-02-01 01:00:00  2020-02-01     2    32.4  54.1  50.6
2020-02-01 02:00:00  2020-02-01     3    31.1  40.9  42.3
2020-02-02 00:00:00  2020-02-02     1    36.8  47.8  46.8
2020-02-02 01:00:00  2020-02-02     2    30.1  50.1  44.2
2020-02-02 02:00:00  2020-02-02     3    30.5  44.0  45.2
```

So basically having the `value` for a certain `category` shown in a different column, as opposed to each row showing its `category`.

Based on the question I linked above, I came up with this:

```
pivoted_df = df.pivot_table(values="value", index=[df.index, "hour", "date", "rating"], columns="category")
```

But the result of that operation is:

```
category                                      C1
date_time           hour date       rating      
2020-02-01 00:00:00 1    2020-02-01 30.0    41.5
2020-02-01 01:00:00 2    2020-02-01 32.4    54.1
2020-02-01 02:00:00 3    2020-02-01 31.1    40.9
2020-02-02 00:00:00 1    2020-02-02 36.8    47.8
2020-02-02 01:00:00 2    2020-02-02 30.1    50.1
2020-02-02 02:00:00 3    2020-02-02 30.5    44.0
```

Which is really not what I'm looking for. And not only that, but I'd be adding `hour`, `date` and `rating` as indexes, which really doesn't look right as I'd like to have those as "normal" columns.

How can I achieve what I mentioned above? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `groupby first` `unstack` on `category`, merge the multilevel columns and rename them.

```
 g=df.groupby(['date_time', 'date', 'hour','category']).first()\
.unstack('category').reset_index().dropna(axis='columns')

g.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in g.columns]#Collapse multiindex
g.rename(columns={'ratingC1':'rating', 'valueC1':'C1','valueC2':'C2'}, inplace=True)#Rename columns

        

      date_time                      date     hour rating    C1    C2
0  2020-02-01 00:00:00 00:00:00  2020-02-01     1    30.0  41.5  51.5
1  2020-02-01 01:00:00 01:00:00  2020-02-01     2    32.4  54.1  50.6
2  2020-02-01 02:00:00 02:00:00  2020-02-01     3    31.1  40.9  42.3
3  2020-02-02 00:00:00 00:00:00  2020-02-02     1    36.8  47.8  46.8
4  2020-02-02 01:00:00 01:00:00  2020-02-02     2    30.1  50.1  44.2
5  2020-02-02 02:00:00 02:00:00  2020-02-02     3    30.5  44.0  45.2
```

**Alternatively**, use pd.pivot

```
 import numpy as np
g=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["date_time","date","hour"],\
                 values=["value","rating"],columns=["category"]).reset_index()#Pivot
g.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in g.columns]#Collapse multiindex
g.rename(columns={'ratingC1':'rating', 'valueC1':'C1','valueC2':'C2'}, inplace=True)#Rename columns
print(g)
```

Comment: Many thanks, you have relieved me of a huge headache. One note though, I mentioned I'd like to keep `date_time` as the index of the dataframe. As such, all I had to do was add `pivoted_df.set_index("date_time", inplace=True)` to use the `date_time` column as an index.

Comment: @wwnde Instead of renaming the columns all over again. you can just use this g.columns = [f'{b}' for a, b in g.columns]